# How to make page-load spinner spin smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, spinner

I have tried both css animations spinners and javascript animated spinners that spin until the $(window).load() fires.  However, due to the intensive js in my document.ready function the animation is constantly interrupted.  My current implementation is as follows:

```
<div id="spinner"></div>
<script>
  $("#spinner").css("top",$(window).height()/2-50);
  $("#spinner").css("left",$(window).width()/2-50);
  var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 20, // The length of each line
  width: 10, // The line thickness
  radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
  speed: 1, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
  left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
   };
  $("#spinner").css("display","inline-block");
  target = document.getElementById('spinner');
  spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
</script>
```

I have a similar problem if the spinner is animated using css.  I have also tried an animated gif image to the same effect.  Finally, using a webworker won't help as far as I know because there is no way to access the main thread's DOM from the webworker.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the DOM cannot be reached from the webworker. Is it necessary that the intensive task ITSELF accesses the DOM?

The problem is that your intensive task is running synchronously, blocking the UI thread from updating. Apart from webworkers the only solution would be to run your intensive task in batches, and leave some time in between batches. I would recommend running the task for no more than 50 ms before allowing a DOM-update, which can be done quite simply:

```
function runTask() {
    // run for 50 ms
    setTimeout(runTask, 1); // Allow DOM-update
}
```

It might still not run as smoothly as you want, in which case you have to keep reducing the amount of ms the task runs between two DOM updates. Not ideal, but unforunately you have to make due with a single thread :(